# How to implement Interstitial iAd in Sprite Kit Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I was wondering if someone could show me how to do the following.

I created a game in Xcode 6.1 using Swift and Sprite Kit. I am trying to implement iAd's interstitial ad every time the "GameOverScene" is being presented. Any help would be much appreciated as I have no clue how to do this using Sprite Kit.

I did found a link where they suggested doing it like this, however when I implement it works, but disable's my user interface and the ability the use the app after the app closes. It does not crash the app, it just looks like everything is disabled after the interstitial is closed:

```
//adding iAd framework

import iAd
//conform iAd delegate

class ViewController: UIViewController,ADInterstitialAdDelegate 


//create instance variable
var interstitial:ADInterstitialAd!
//default iAd interstitials does not provide close button so we need to     create one manually

var placeHolderView:UIView!
var closeButton:UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//iAD interstitial
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("runAd:"),    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}




//iAD interstitial
func runAd(notification:NSNotification){
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self,     selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
cycleInterstitial()
}

func cycleInterstitial(){

// Clean up the old interstitial...
//  interstitial.delegate = nil;
// and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when
interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
interstitial.delegate = self;
}

func presentInterlude(){
// If the interstitial managed to load, then we'll present it now.
if (interstitial.loaded) {

    placeHolderView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(placeHolderView)

    closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y:  25, width: 25, height: 25))
    closeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "error"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("close"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    self.view.addSubview(closeButton)


    interstitial.presentInView(placeHolderView)
}
}

// iAd Delegate Mehtods

// When this method is invoked, the application should remove the view from the screen and tear it down.
// The content will be unloaded shortly after this method is called and no new content will be loaded in that view.
// This may occur either when the user dismisses the interstitial view via the dismiss button or
// if the content in the view has expired.

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
interstitial = nil

cycleInterstitial()
}


func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(_interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
interstitial = nil

println("called just before dismissing - action finished")

}

// This method will be invoked when an error has occurred attempting to get advertisement content.
// The ADError enum lists the possible error codes.
func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!,
didFailWithError error: NSError!){
    cycleInterstitial()
}


//Load iAd interstitial
func dislayiAdInterstitial() {
//iAd interstitial
presentInterlude()
}


func close() {
placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
interstitial = nil

}
```

And then again someone said add this to my scene would just do it :

```
func fullScreenAd() {
if self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation() {
    println("ad loaded")
}
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, when the iAd is dismissed, a blank display is left. The functions interstitialAdActionDidFinish() and interstitialAdDidUnload() are never called.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve this. You need to add these lines to your ViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

   var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!
   var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()
   // make myScene the SKScene you want to display after the ad goes away
   var myScene: SKScene?


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

    // prepare ads
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.None
    loadInterstitialAd()

   }

// MARK: interstitial add support functions

    func showAd() {
        interstitialAdView = UIView()
        interstitialAdView.frame = self.view.bounds
        view.addSubview(interstitialAdView)

        interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }

    func loadInterstitialAd() {
        print("loadInterstitialAd")
        interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()
        interstitialAd.delegate = self
    }

    func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("AdWillLoad")
    }

    func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("AdDidLoad")
        /*
        showAd()
        */
    }

    func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("AdActionDidFinish")
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.presentScene(myScene!)
    }

    func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        print("AdActionShouldBegin")
        return true
    }

    func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        print("AdDidFailWithError")
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }

    func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
        print("AdDidUnload")
        interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your game code, in one of the scenes, do this:

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! GameViewController

if viewController.interstitialAd.loaded {
    viewController.showAd()
} else {
    print("Ad Not Loaded")
    // scene change if no ad ready to be shown
    self.scene!.view?.presentScene(viewController.myScene!, transition: transition)
}
```