# How to implement iAd interstitial with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

I want to implement iAd interstitial Ad in my Spritekit game and experiencing troubles with adding it. That's how I'm doing it:

```
import iAd
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

var interAd:ADInterstitialAd?
var interAdView = UIView()
var closeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 70, 44)
    closeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    closeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    closeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    closeButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "closeAd:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    closeButton.enabled = false
    closeButton.setTitle("skip", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    closeButton.enabled = true
    closeButton.setNeedsLayout()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAd", name: "showIntAD", object: nil)

func prepareAd() {
    println(" --- AD: Try Load ---")
    // Attempt to load a new ad:
    interAd = ADInterstitialAd()
    interAd?.delegate = self
}

func showAd() -> Bool {
    if interAd != nil && interAd!.loaded {
        interAdView = UIView()
        interAdView.frame = self.view!.bounds
        self.view?.addSubview(interAdView)

        interAd!.presentInView(interAdView)
        UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

        interAdView.addSubview(closeButton)
    }
    return interAd?.loaded ?? false
}

func closeAd(sender: UIButton) {
    adFinished()
}

func adFinished() {
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interAdView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println(" --- AD: Load Success ---")
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println(" --- AD: Unload --- ")
}

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println(" --- ADD: Action Finished --- ")
    adFinished()
}

func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(" --- AD: Error --- ")
    println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to summon iAd in the gameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, ADInterstitialAdDelegate {

 func showAds(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showIntAD", object: nil)
}

//Those two are required by Apple to conform "AdInterstitial" protocol
func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println(" --- AD: Unload --- ")
}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(" --- AD: Error --- ")
    println(error.localizedDescription)
}
}
```

And I have a testButton which should show an Ad if I click it. It shows nothing! Please help me, I'm trying to do this almost a week!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more easily. In your `viewDidLoad` method enable `Automatic` presentation policy and use `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` method to present an interstitial. I have created a `showIntersitialAd` which does just that.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
}

private func showIntersitialAd() { //call this method whenever you want to show an interstitial
    self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
}
```

Comment: But I still need to post `func interstitialAd` and `func interstitialAdDidUnload`, right? Because otherwise it gives me an error and says that `gameviewcontroller doesn't conform to AdInterstitialAD protocol`.

Comment: Remove `ADInterstitialAdDelegate` from your declaration.

Comment: I tried it, put `Automatic` in viewDidLoad and when I tried to make a `showInterstitialAd()` func in GameScene it gave me an error: `GameScene doesn't have a member named 'requestInterstitialAdPresentation'`

Comment: Maybe I should do `showInterstitialAd` in GameViewController and use NSNotificationCenter to access it in GameScene?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a game with gameviewcontroller and SKScenes then my answer here might help you, because I was doing the same.

[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218976/how-to-implement-interstitial-iad-in-sprite-kit-swift/36455185#36455185)